# Mysql Calculate Percentage Of Selected Rows

Tags: mysql, sum, cross-join

I'm sorry if my question irrelevant. Because I'm not expert of mysql.

I have surveys in my website. If someone votes my survey, i want to show survey results to the voter.

Here is the DB Structure;

`surveys` **Table** (Includes Survey Name Description and `survey_id`)

[image: Surveys]

`survey_choices` **Table** (Includes Survey Chocies and related with `survey_id` to Surveys Table)

[image: Survey Choices]

I'm trying to calculate only visible survey choices %percentage.

If i have only 1 survey, it's calculating correct results. But if i have more than 1 survey, mysql calculating whole `survey_vote_count` values of all table.

Here is my MySQL query;

```
SELECT 
survey_vote_id, survey_vote_name, survey_vote_count, survey_id, 
survey_vote_count * 100 / t.s AS survey_percentage
FROM survey_votes
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(survey_vote_count) AS s FROM survey_votes) t
WHERE visibility = :visibility
AND survey_id = :surveyId
ORDER BY `survey_votes`.`order_id` ASC
```

How can i calculate for eg only `survey_id = 1 and visibility = 1` %percentage = %100?

Any help will greatly appricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the same condition to your cross join. At the moment, in your select you sum all survey_vote_count without the same where condition (visibility and survey_id.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. But how? `SELECT SUM(survey_vote_count) AS s FROM survey_votes WHERE survey_id = surveyId AND visibility = :visibility` ?